# Laptop stuck at OS selection page

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, sound, keyboard

I have a Toshiba Satellite c640 laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7 installed. It was working fine for more than two years and for the last month I didn't use it. Yesterday I tried to turn on my laptop, it got stuck on the following screen.

[image]

I am unable to select the loader using keyboard arrow keys and also Ubuntu is not loading by default (it was working fine earlier if I didn't choose loader, Ubuntu will be loaded after 8 seconds).

More details: I am getting a continuous beep sound for some time before the screen shown above appears.

EDIT:
I cannot say ubuntu is crashed as the system is not loading any OS and is stuck in the OS selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a continuous beeping sound while loading is likely a keyboard fault. check for a stuck key.

Answer (score 2):

1. Does the BIOS entry key work? If yes, try booting to an Ubuntu installer, and seeing if the arrow keys work. If not, use Ubuntu to change the GRUB settings.
2. If you can't get into BIOS, try a USB keyboard. AFAIK as long as they are plugged into the root hub GRUB recognizes them.
3. If all else fails, clear CMOS (Usually by connecting two pins on the motherboard, see motherboard docs) and see if it boots to external by default.

Hope this helps (this is my first answer on this community!)

Comment: Good answer.  Proposal for enhancement: explain how to clear CMOS.